# How to get proxy from text file c#/.net?

Tags: c#, url, proxy, webbrowser-control, host

I have saved some url's in a text(link.txt) file & some proxy(proxy.txt) in another text file.

now i want to use different proxy for each url.

like:

- www.google.com  202.56.232.117:8080
- www.facebook.com  506.78.781.987:9001
- www.twitter.com 749.961.73.459:8008

this is my code but i don't know how to use different proxy(proxy.txt) for each url.

please tell me how to make this work.

```
try
{

    foreach (string sr in File.ReadAllLines("link.txt"))
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(sr);
    }
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Internet Connection not found","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     this.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't think those lines are valid urls - they have spaces in them, separating what looks like a valid url from some sort of IP-address-type thing (though even those are invalid - the octets should only go to 255!) Are the IP addresses supposed to be the proxies to use for each url?

Comment: these are only example ulr's from link.txt file & IP Addresses from proxy.txt file. & i want to call both files. first call for url & secand call for using proxy to load webpage.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Public Sub SetProxy(ByVal ServerName As String, ByVal port As Integer)
Try            
Dim regkey1 As RegistryKey
regkey1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", True)
regkey1.SetValue("ProxyServer", ServerName + ":" + port.ToString(), RegistryValueKind.Unknown)
regkey1.SetValue("ProxyEnable", True, RegistryValueKind.DWord)   
regkey1.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
End Sub
```